# Convert Hive column from String to timestamp having NaT values

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, nosql

I have a Hive table where column name 'date' has values of the format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'. The datatype is of String type. However, I need to convert it to timestamp as per my end users.

These are lots of values of that column with values 'NaT'. When I am casting that column with cast(data as timestamp) the entire column is showing null(even for values 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'). 
What is the best work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')) as timestamp)
```

Comment: Date is not a timestamp

Comment: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid function 'replace'

Comment: Also, the values can be "", NULL as well. I suppose that's causing problem in typecasting. Because I was able to typecast other column with similar format successfully. There wasn't any NaT,NaN,NULL etc.